# Trying to check input textbox for time

Tags: regex, validation, syntax, input, textbox

I have to make this overview of questions and the user has to be able to insert a time.
To do this I made 2 textboxes, 1 is for the hour input and 1 is for the minute input.

What I want to do now is check if the values aren't to high to be correct.

Example:
The hour value cant be higher than 23 and the minute cant be higher than 59.

What is the best method for checking this?
I've been thinking about if statements but maybe there is a much more efficient way to get this done?
Maybe regular expressions, although I wouldnt know a correct syntax for this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: regex is probably not the best tool for this. what language are you using?

Comment: Im sorry, should have said that aswell.
Im using VB.net, together with ASP.net.
But the regex will all be in the code behind aka VB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it has to be a regex:

```
^(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9])$
```

will validate the hour and

```
^[0-5]?[0-9]$
```

will validate the minute.

**Explanation for the "Hours" regex:** (you can figure out the minutes yourself easily):

```
^        # Match start of string
(?:      # Match either...
 2[0-3]  # 2, followed by 0, 1, 2 or 3,
|        # or... 
 [01]?   # 0 or 1 (optional; the empty string is OK, too), followed by
 [0-9]   # any digit
)        # End of group
$        # Match end of string
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but how does that work then?
Could you explain how those validate hours and minutes?

Comment: Okay thank you very much for that.
Its clear now.
I would vote +1 for this post but it wont let me because I need 15 rep or more. So Answer = + 1 :P
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If statements are definitely the way to go. There's no reason to use a regular expression for something so simple... it's like using a sledgehammer to place a small nail into a wall. If statements are also very efficient and easy to read... there's no reason to use regex for what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback aswell. 
I have already used it in my code and I like the way it works now.
Regex is something I will most likely use more often in a while if I see what projects are on the agenda at work.
At least my co-worker said that to me.
I will try the if statements too and just look what works better/faster.
Thanks for thinking with me/us